# Using Part[[i]] to defined a function

Tags: function-construction

I would like to define a function like this

```
f[x_, v_] := Part[m, 4, 1]
```

where `m = {{x^2}, {x^3}, {x^6}, {v x^4}}`. but I can't assign values to the function. For exemple, for `f[2, 4]`, Mathematica gives me v x^4, but the answer should be 2*4^4=512.

**EDIT**

I can just define `m` as a function: `m[x_, v_] := {{x^2}, {x^3}, {x^6}, {v x^4}};`. Then we can use `f[x_, v_] := Part[m[x, v], 4, 1];`. This solve the problem.

Comment: Why can't you just define it as `f[x_, v_] := v x^4`? Understanding what your context is and what constraints pertain would help us help you.

Comment: @lericr In my original problem m is 10x1 and I  have expressions that are more complicated.

Comment: what does "10x1" mean?

Comment: Okay, so do you want to define multiple functions, each depending on one of the more complicated expressions, or do you want a way to choose which complicated expression the function depens on, or do you want to be able to change which part you extract from the complicated expressions, or what?

Answer (score 2):

Given

```
m = {{x^2}, {x^3}, {x^6}, {v x^4}}
```

you could define `f` in two ways:

```
f[x_, v_] = Part[m, 4, 1] (* use Set rather than SetDelayed *)
f[x_, v_] := Evaluate[Part[m, 4, 1]] (* force evaluation of m before f is actually defined *)
```

I don't actually recommend either of these as they use a hidden dependency. I.e. they depend on `m`, and so anyone needs to know what `m` is before they can understand the function. Also, there is the question of whether you need `f` to stay synchronized with `m` or not. I.e. if `m` changes should `f` change? How you define `f` will depend on this requirement.

So, if you provide more context, we can give you better alternatives.